Почему while и bot.polling не работают вместе,

Пишу бота в ТГ
While глушит bot.polling не понимаю как их совместить

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.

Вот здесь пример как было объединено с while

Этот вопрос похож на: Как сделать, что-бы работала функция while:True и bot.polling()?. Если вы считаете его другим, пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос, чётко обозначив отличие и/или почему ответы на вопрос не помогли в вашем случае.

Цикл while True — это бесконечный цикл, который никогда не заканчивается, а значит что те действия которые происходят в цикле будут повторяться до тех пор, пока вы сами не остановите программу
